# Underwater acoustics: particle motion

Tags: acoustics, water, oceanography

The properties of an acoustic wave field depend on the mechanical properties of the supporting medium, including the density, and the bulk modulus. With increasing density, the propagation speed of the wave decreases, whilst with increasing bulk modulus, or stiffness of the material, the speed increases (cited from the book 'Applied Underwater Acoustics' by Bjørnø, 2017)

It is often stated that particle motion/velocity/acceleration sensitivity is advantageous in water (e.g. invertebrates and fishes mostly detect particle acceleration rather than pressure). Is it correct? If you take the same sound source (given intensity and frequency), how will the particle motion/velocity/acceleration compare in water, in air, and in a solid?